# Django view is not rendering a template when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to a render a template in view when I click a button in another template.  I make an ajax call to a method in view, but I am not sure what is wrong with it.  I am not able to render another template, am I doing something wrong?

```
my view.py

@csrf_exempt
def checkLogin (request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        param = request.POST.get('param', None)
        param1 = request.POST.get('param1', None)
        if (param=="admin" and param1=="admin"):
            Datenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            return render(request,'sample/test.html',{'Datenow': Datenow})
        else:
            Datenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            return render(request,'sample/login.html',{'Datenow': Datenow})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

This is my ajax call in my template:

```
    loginbt.onclick = function() { 
            var uName = $('#username').val();
            var pWord = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: '/sample/checkLogin/',                            // some data url
            data: {param: uName, param1: pWord},       // some params  
            success: function (response) {                  // callback
                if (response.result === 'OK') {
                    if (response.data && typeof(response.data) === 'object') {
                       window.alert("its working");
                    }
                } else {
                    // handle an unsuccessful response
                }
            }
           });
```

}

I get a `200 OK` result when I click the button in the template, but the template just does not change.  Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Does your `window.alert` event fire successfully?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would cause the template to be displayed anywhere? If you want to update the HTML with the template response, you need to do that in your success function.

Comment: Why do you think your page would change? You're returning an HTML document to an ajax function and that function does nothing except displaying an alert. With ajax, your django view should return a JSON document so that your ajax function can process that and change the HTML DOM tree accordingly.

Comment: @souldeux,nope it doesn't

Comment: @solarissmoke yes,but the window.alert is not getting fired in the onsuccess method

Comment: @dirkgroten i'm not sure what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the js callback of the ajax call.

You are returning some html from django **but** in your js callback your are testing the response as it is JSON data.

```
if (response.result === 'OK') {
   if (response.data && typeof(response.data) === 'object')
```

You are checking for a JSON structure like this:

```
{
   result: "OK",
   data: {
   }
}
```

Please fix your code appropriately.

Comment: i'm new to this,could you help me as to what exactly might be the problem
??